# How to use Index/Match or other function to get cell data left of lookup value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` to get the following to work.

[image]

You will see on the bottom ride side of the image that there is a "High" value. What I am them trying to do is search the table to the left to find that value. Then, I am wanting the output to be the "Floorplan" name. So essentially, I am wanting "D" to show up in J14.

I originally tried `VLOOKUP` but learned that the first column needed to be the lookup value, so I am trying the index/match route. I cannot get it to work though. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Formula being used:

`=INDEX($A$9:$D$15,MATCH($I$14,A9:D15,4),1)`

Comment: yes to have the lookup be something other than the first column you use `XLOOKUP`. If that is not available to you, then perhaps updating `MATCH($I$14,A9:D15,4)` to `MATCH($I$14,D9:D15,0)` might work...

Comment: @gns100 That did work! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `gns100` commented, `MATCH()` was failing as the range to match in was not a single column (or row). And using `XLOOKUP()` works nicely here as well as the particulars do make it unsuitable as they do sometimes. It follows the same basic approach as `INDEX/MATCH` in that it is given the same basics:  lookup value, where to look for that value, where to go to in order to find what to return.

`VLOOKUP()` CAN do the trick, if for some reason you prefer it. `INDEX/MATCH` works in any Excel version that has `VLOOKUP()`, I believe, so with the small adjustment `gns100` showed, you can always use that when compatibility with older versions is needed.

`VLOOKUP()` does it by using `INDEX()` to create a virtual table for its second parameter, one that contains only the lookup column and the results column, and in that order. For instance:

```
=VLOOKUP($I$14,  INDEX(A9:D15, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A9:D15)) ),{4,1}),  2,  FALSE)
```

The `{4,1}` ("array constant") tells `INDEX()` to return the 4th column first, and 1st column second giving you a (virtual) two column lookup table in which `VLOOKUP()` can "look right" to find the result. So it still "looks right" but the effect is it "looks left."

That bit in the middle, `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A9:D15))` is just the old school way of getting a series from "1" to whatever so it specifies to return all rows. Nowadays, a simple `SEQUENCE( ROWS(A1:D15) )` would do, but that doesn't go back past `XLOOKUP()` so... The reason it must be there is that when you specify either rows or columns (or "areas" in some other uses) using an array constant directly, or anything that generates an array constant during its calculation, then Excel requires the other parameter be completely specified rather than using just, say, `,,` (nothing for the row parameter) or `,0,` ("0" for the row parameter), either of which specifies "ALL" rows to Excel.

Yeah, old school was obnoxious. Gotta love `XLOOKUP()` and `FILTER()`!

You can use a similar technique with the rows, though composed slightly differently, to make `INDEX()` create a virtual table that is bottom up, top down... last row is now first, first row is now last. This can let you find "the newest date" and similar kinds of things in which you want to search from the bottom upwards.

All are just for compatibility with older versions though as `XLOOKUP()` only fails to do what is needed in uncommon circumstances. And the similar approaches that do what `FILTER()` does now are also, of course, only needed for older version compatibility.

One interesting thing that `INDEX()` can do that is not yet obsolete, not quite anyway (I think the new array handling functions might make this obsolete as well), is that it can transpose a range in all four variations, not just left-right becoming up-down and vice versa like with `TRANSPOSE()`. But the fact you've never heard of doing that on the million Excel help sites probably means it's never needed in the real world.